# How to solve the "menu cannot be resolved or is not a field" error

Tags: android, menu

I got the following issue with my menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The file `main_menu.xml` was indeed created in the `res/menu` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/prefs" android:title="@string/pref"></item>    
</menu>
```

Eclipse couldn't resolve `R.menu` and generated the following error:

```
menu cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours googling and browsing StackOverflow. I simply fixed my issue by removing the R.java file in the "gen" directory. It forced Eclipse to regenerate it and R.menu got resolved.

I hope it will help others.

Comment: a simple **Project -> Clean** would also fix this

Comment: I lost hours as I thought Eclipse would notice I added a res/menu folder. I didn't know about the "Project->Clean" option. Thanks for your comment.